# Controlling LED's with LPC1768

Tags: c++, mbed

I am trying to write a program that controls a set of leds based on different switches that get pressed. When switch one gets pressed red leds should turn on. When switch two gets pressed green leds should turn on. And when switch 3 gets pressed a red and a green led goes off.

When I include just one section of code, say the red led portion, it will work ok. But when I add in code for switches 2 or 3 nothing works.

```
int main() {
red1 = 0;
red2 = 0;
red3 = 0;

green1 = 1;
green2 = 1;
green3 = 1;

while(true) {

    //controls for switch 1
    if (switch1 == true)
    {    
        red1 = 1; 
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch1 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10); 
    }
    else if (switch1 == true && red1 == 1)
    {
        red2 = 1;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch1 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10); 
    }
    else if (switch1 == true && red1 == 1 && red2 == 1)
    {
        red3 = 1;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch1 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10); 
    }

    //controls for switch 2
    if (switch2 == true)
    {    
        green1 = 0; 
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch2 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10); 
    }
    else if (switch2 == true && green1 == 0)
    {
        green1 = 0;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch2 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10); 
    }
    else if (switch2 == true && green1 == 0 && green2 == 0)
    {
        green3 = 0;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch2 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10); 
    }

    //controls for switch 3
    if (switch3 == true && red3 == 1 && green3 == 0)
    {
        red3 = 0;
        green3 = 1;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch3 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10);
    }
    else if(switch3 == true && red2 == 1 && green2 == 0)
    {
        red2 = 0;
        green2 = 1;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch3 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10);
    }
    else if (switch3 == true && red1 == 1 && green1 == 0)
    {
        red1 = 0;
        green1 = 1;
        wait_ms(10); 
        wait(0.4);  
        while (switch3 == 1) {};
        wait_ms(10);
    }
}
```

I have no error messages and I know my mbed is wired properly because I did some simple tests to make sure each switch and light is working. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a problem with your if statements.

In a simplified code below, (2) and (3) will never get called. Even when `switch1 == true` and `red1 == 1`, the if statement evaluates (1)  first and (2) is not evaluated.

```cpp
if (switch1 == true) // (1)
{    
    red1 = 1; 
}
else if (switch1 == true && red1 == 1) // (2)
{
    red2 = 1; 
}
else if (switch1 == true && red1 == 1 && red2 == 1) //(3)
{
    red3 = 1; 
}
```

I think below is what you wanted.

```cpp
if (switch1 == true && red1 == 1 && red2 == 1)
{   
    red3 = 1; 
}
else if (switch1 == true && red1 == 1)
{
    red2 = 1; 
}
else if (switch1 == true)
{
    red1 = 1; 
}
```